# java How to pass this to another constructor(Constructor Overload)?

Tags: java, android

```
CustomView(Context c, Boolean animate) {
    super(c);
    this(c, animate, this);
}

CustomView(Context c, Boolean animate, CustomView bind) {
    super(c);

    //other actions

}
```

I want to pass this to another constructor with more params than this, but I get an error that:

```
Cannot reference "this" before supertype constructor has been called
```

even tough I call super(c) before use "this", is there a way to overcome this error?

Comment: do you have a constructor that takes a context a boolean and a CustomView as parameters ?

Comment: @Blackbelt yes exactly

Comment: @Chandrakanth I've tried to remove super(c), but the error still lives, maybe I didn't understand your toughts exactly?

Comment: I am curious. Can you post the other constructor ?

Comment: What is the purpose of passing this into self constructor??

Comment: Remove super and all will be working.

Comment: please, read any Java article about inheritance!

Comment: @Blackbelt, I've posted the second constructor, so the idea is: if I create a CustomView and pass to it a CustomView as parameter to bind then the second constructor is called, but if not it is binded to itself, well anyway if the idea is not the best, I want to know why this error occurs technically, yes technically

Comment: why downvote?..is there anything wrong? I don't know why people press downvote without telling the reason , I think this is stupid

Comment: @user4642850 you already have the solution posted in my answer - edited and compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have 3 calls to constructor. You need to pick one of them

```
CustomView(Context c, Boolean animate) {
    super(c); //fisrt call
    this(c, animate, this); //second call
}
CustomView(Context c, Boolean animate, CustomView bind) {
    super(c); //third call

    //other actions

}
```

you should do something like

```
CustomView(Context c, Boolean animate) {
    this(c, animate, null);
}
CustomView(Context c, Boolean animate, CustomView bind) {
    super(c); //third call
     if(bind==null) {bind=this}
    //do whatever you like with your "bindings"
}
```

EDIT:

I have found out, that OP can actually have some troubles. Eg. This code does not compile!:

```
class Foo{
    Foo(Object o){

    }
}

class FooBar extends Foo {
    FooBar(Object o, Boolean a){
        this(o,a,this);
    }
    FooBar(Object o, Boolean a, FooBar fb){
        super(o);           
    }
}
```

errror on `this(o,a,this);` line is as follows

```
Cannot refer to 'this' nor 'super' while explicitly invoking a constructor
```

So the logic solution to his, is to pass `null` insteed of this, and have handled it in extended constructor.

Comment: I understand what are you saying, but somehow I'am still getting this error, I've did what you say...It just cannot reference "this" BEFORE the supertype constructor is called, but what you are saying is the opposite, we are calling "this" before the super constructor is called thus we even don't call it , I'am right?

Comment: no, the same error as before, looks like I will have to find another way to realize this, this way it won't work...:(

Comment: Yes, I have tested it, and posted proper solution, you were right. I have mentioned it in edit.

Comment: well, this makes more sense, looks like this is the only way by now :(, answer accepted

Comment: @user4642850 I must admit, that at the first glance, eveything looks fine, but when you think about it makes sense why such construct is disallowed.

Comment: Fair enough,This works elegantly.But I still think you can do a design change which would void this problem

Answer (score 0):

See the workflow :

`CustomView(c,animate)` ---> `CustomView(c)` --->`CustomView(c,animate, bind)` ---> `CustomView(c)`

when you do `this(c,animate, this)` and then call `super(c)` in  `CustomView(c,animate, bind)`,then

`Cannot reference "this" before supertype constructor has been called` occurs.

instead ,what if you did this

```
CustomView(Context c, Boolean animate) {
    this(c, animate, this);
}

CustomView(Context c, Boolean animate, CustomView bind) {
    super(c);

    //other actions

}
```

Comment: wow bro nice try, but this won't work, its the same as the answer above, if you don't believe me just try it by yourself

Comment: Just opening eclipse :)